# Msg 2714, Level 16, State 3, Procedure SP_LOGIN, Line 6 There is already an object named 'SP_LOGIN' in the database

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

[image]

hi. I am a beginner learner I found this problem in the picture I tried to solve it by search I found that I should change the name in stored procedure I did and it
worked but later I tried again to execute it appear again please help.thanks

Comment: I can see that you are using MS SQL Server, what version do you have?

Comment: Why are you trying to execute it again? It is telling you that it is already created. If you want to update it you need `ALTER`. Also don't use the `sp_` prefix for your own procs. It is reserved by Microsoft. In fact don't use any such prefix. It is just noise. Also you shouldn't be storing passwords in plain text.

Comment: My MS SQL version is 10.0.162

Comment: thanks to all, Can you help me create the above command correctly with out sp prefix

Comment: Best practise aside, do you mean you are trying to call the proc? like, `exec sp_login @uname = '<username>', @upass = '@password'`?

Comment: yes, please can you help

Answer (score 0):

I would do a couple things:  1) Change the procedure name to usp_login... sp_ being the procedure name standard for MS procedures.  2) change the CREATE PROCEDURE to an ALTER PROCEDURE.